# Circular patterns at bottom of rock, is it a fossil?

Tags: fossils, paleontology

The image below was taken on a hike.  Circular patterns at bottom (it is flatter on this face and round otherwise) appear either man-made or possibly it is a fossil.

Any idea what this could be?

[image: Rock of interest:]

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science StackExchange! Could you provide a bit more information? Please follow this guide: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/125/56.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a picture of the chipped side. It's useful to see an unweathered surface when identifying rocks

Comment: There look to be some radial markings in the centre which lead me to suspect that this is a fossil but I'm no expert on what it could be.

Comment: OTOH From this single photo with lack of information, this could be concrete

Comment: It could be a concretion having a image of the other side and the broken surface would help a lot. Density and were it was found will help as well. If the other side is broken off you might have a fossil or at least a cast of one.

Comment: The depth of lake or small dirty pool of rain could be create this loop by change of the depth.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I apologize of the lack of detail.  It was a long hike a few hours away so by the time I posted and read the guide it was too late for me to take more photos, check hardness, etc...  Probably only other useful information is the rock was at the bottom of a gorge/valley near a creek bed.  Also, scale, that rock is about 14-16" in diameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The face of the rock with the round center portion looks strongly like a Rugosa or Horn Coral.  I suggest it is a Rugosa coral because of the center with the radial lines out from the center and the clear edge surrounding the radial lines.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugosa.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The distinct feature that made me suspect fossil was the radial lines out from the center as well, in which case Rugosa makes sense.